# maximum sum of a list

Tags: python, list

I am quite new to python. Just out of curiosity is there a simpler approach to find maximum sum of a list that includes both negative and positive integers?
for ex:

```
IN_1
    l = [1,2,3] 
OUT
    6

IN_2
    l = [1,-2,-3]
OUT
    1

IN_3
    l = [-1,-2,-3]
OUT
    -1
```

If it was the case where IN_3 would return 0, then the approach was quite simple. Just removing all the negative elements and using sum.

```
l = [item for item in l if item >= 0]
sum(l)
```

The code worked pretty well for IN_1 and IN_2.

But I am having trouble in 3rd case IN_3 where it would necessarily take a number that is least negative and return it.

Comment: What was your approach?

Comment: what is your expected output on given input?

Comment: I believe what you are looking for is the maximum subarray problem.  See for example Kadane's algorithm.

Comment: What is 'maximum sum'? Is it the sum of the leftmost elements of the list, cutting off the list so that the sum is maximized? Or do you want to pick only some elements (in any order, not necessarily from the left), so that the sum is maximized?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
l = input('').split()
s = sum([int(i) for i in l if int(i)>0]) or int(max(l, key=int))
```

Comment: deleting a negatively-scored answer and supplying the same answer again as zero score could be looked upon as _fraudulent_. the answer is ok, though. I do not understand you deleted it in the first place.

Comment: [read about reposting negatively scored answer here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/289222/user-deleted-downvoted-answer-to-reanswer-with-the-same-answer)

Comment: @PatrickArtner I have missed a part in my answer at first place, then I got a downvote, then I edited and my answer works just fine, but the guy who downvoted my answer never came to see the edit.

Answer (score 0):

```
def getsum(l):
   return sum({False:[max(l)]}.get(bool([i for i in l if i >0]),[i for i in l if i >0]))
print(getsum([1,2,3]))
print(getsum([1,-2,-3]))
print(getsum([-1,-2,-3]))
```

Output:

```
6
1
-1
```

Comment: Extremely inefficient, tho.

Comment: @zwer Yeah, i was lazy... for doing an if statement

Answer (score 0):

You already outlined the approach so the implementation is simply:

```
def max_sum(l):
    return sum(i for i in l if i > 0) or max(l)
print(max_sum([1,2,3]))
print(max_sum([1,-2,-3]))
print(max_sum([-1,-2,-3]))
```

This outputs:

```
6
1
-1
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you only have two cases to worry about:

1. The list contains only negative integers, i.e.

   if max(list) < 0: 
          return max(list)
2. Some positive integers and potentially some negative integers (or none), i.e.

   if max(list) > 0:
       filter out negatives and return the sum of what is left

Answer (score 0):

```
l = [-1,-2,-3]
s = sum([i for i in l if i > 0])
s =  s  if s > 0 else max(l)
print(s)
```

Answer (score -1):

I have done from very basic and simple coding
My Answer as Follows:

```
l = [1,2,3]
m = [1,-2,-3]
j = [-1,-2,-3]

i = 0
for k in m:
    i+=k
print(i)
```

I checked for all lists.

Comment: for m and j the answers should be 1 and -1 - you are just doing `sum(m)` and `sum(j)`